# Simple way to check if character is not from a string?

Tags: java

Is there a tool I can use to check if a character is not part of a string?
Here is what I am trying to do in pseudocode

```
String delims = " \t*+-/()[]"
char x;
if(x is not in delims)
{
   do this
}
```

Comment: String.contains, String.indexOf, ...

Comment: The "tool" is called java library. I'll give you a hint look here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Would be something like this: `if (!delims.contains("x")) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

String.contains() will help you.
It's a library of JAVA not a tool ;)

```
String delims = " \t*+-/()[]"
    char x='/';
    if(!delims.contains(Character.toString(x))) //not contains
    {
       do this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method Java.lang.String.contains()[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm)

```
    public class StringDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String str1 = "tutorials point", str2 = "http://";

      CharSequence cs1 = "int";

      // string contains the specified sequence of char values
      boolean retval = str1.contains(cs1);
      System.out.println("Method returns : " + retval);

      // string does not contain the specified sequence of char value
      retval = str2.contains("_");   
      System.out.println("Methods returns: " + retval);
   }
}
```

This code is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm.
I hope i could help you!

Greethings! :)

Noixes

Comment: be aware that tutorialspoint isn't exactly the most reliable source to learn from. To quote Tutorialspoint: "A variable declared with final modifier is known as final variable in Java. The value of final variable cannot be changed once it is initialized. These final variables are CONSTANT in Java". Unfortunately, for over 90% of variables, this is nonsense. So, always beware any hidden errors.

Comment: Yeah, but we should evalutate every source of information we can find in the internet. :) Sometimes it is great, sometimes it is wrong .. But yeah, you right